# phpDocumentor2 not showing packages in html output

Tags: phpdoc

I am trying to get [phpDocumentor2](http://www.phpdoc.org/) to build API documentation for a PHP project I am working on.
The problem is that the HTML output landing page does not show the packages defined in my project. It only shows "Global ()" package.

I believe I am properly using the @package tag for my classes. phpDocumentor version is 2.0.0b4.

In my efforts to find the bottom of the problem I found a project that is [already using phpdoc2](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/api/). I downloaded that project and tried to build the documentation myself as it has a `phpdoc.dist.xml` file in its codebase root. I got the same problem: no packages in HTML output landing page, while the vendor's one is showing them (SimplePie, CodeIgniter, Streams etc.).

How can I get my phpdoc output showing packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are experiencing a bug in the early betas.  Keep watching for new beta releases, as they are coming out quite fast as bugs are reported and fixed.

Comment: Many thanks, I did not expect that beta version could be so much more buggy than alpha. Got it work with alpha-12!